# Como atrapar valor de un <ul></ul> con ANGULARJS?

Tags: html5, angularjs

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente al obtener el `<li>` seleccionado de una lista `<ul>`.

Penseé que sería igual como en un `select` que solamente se le coloca el `ng-model` y ya, pero esto es diferente.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
        Categorias <span class="caret"></span>  
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" >
        <li ng-repeat="objeto in objeto" value="{{objeto.idCategoria}}" ng-model="categoriaElejida" title="{{objeto.idCategoria}}"><a href="#!tecnologia">{{objeto.nombre}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: coloca algun codigo en tu pregunta porfavor, para que asi podamos ayudarte.

Comment: `<li class="dropdown">
       <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
        Categorias <span class="caret"></span> 
       </a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" >
        <li ng-repeat="objeto in objeto" value="{{objeto.idCategoria}}" ng-model="categoriaElejida" title="{{objeto.idCategoria}}"><a href="#!tecnologia">{{objeto.nombre}}</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>`

Comment: Ese es el codigo bro no se como podria tomarlo

Answer (score 1):

En este caso no puedes hacer algo asi de sencillo como usar `ng-model`, pero puedes usar una alternativa para saber que categoria el usuario ha seleccionado usando `ng-click` de esta forma:

*(Ten en cuenta que modifique el HTML y omiti algunos atributos que habias puesto para mayor brevedad pero lo mas importante es esta parte que adicione: `ng-click="ctrl.seleccionarCategoria(objeto.idCategoria)"`)*

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
        Categorias <span class="caret"></span>  
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" >
        <li ng-repeat="objeto in objetos">
            <a href="#!tecnologia"
               ng-click="ctrl.seleccionarCategoria(objeto.idCategoria)">
             {{objeto.nombre}}
            </a>
         </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

En el **controlador** seria algo asi:

```
//...
function seleccionarCategoria(idCategoria) {
    ctrl.idCategoria = idCategoria;
}
//...
```

De esta forma, podrias realizar cualquier procesamiento posterior teniendo en cuenta el id de la ultima categoria que se selecciono. Pr ejemplo, asi:

```
//...
function mostrarCategoria() {
    console.log("el id de la categoria es: " + ctrl.idCategoria);
}
//...
```

Comment: JJAJJAA que excelente logica yo tambien pense en lo mismo, perdon por responder tarde pero gracias de igual forma